# Replacing a function in a Ruby source file with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace

Firstly, I am using Ruby 2.2.0 with Rails 4.2.0 (so I have ActiveSupport installed if anything in there is helpful for this task).

**The What**

What I want to be able to do is read a Ruby file and take any methods which are declared in it, then write / overwrite them into another Ruby file which might already have those methods declared.

I want to do this in the source file, it is to be done as a kind of pre-processor thing, not at runtime.  I am not talking about [Open Classes](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html), I want to permanently edit a source file.

If there is nothing then I will do something with reading files, going line by line looking for `def` and `end` statements but I am wondering if something like this already exists?

**The Why**

Partly to work with and partly to see if I could, I wrote a script in Ruby which parses an XMI file generated by ArgoXML, using some further constraints in my drawing so that my script knows when I am using `has_many` or `has_many :through`, the latter I used for all my habtm.

It then creates Rails generator commands in a shell script for all of my models etc, and uses awk to inject any relations which need setup manually (as in not in the line with the generator).

This quickly created models and database entries for some 100 tables.  Obviously though running my script again removes any existing files (or asks me 100 times what I want to do, which given that most of the time is destroy, I would rather not).

**Example:**

I am happy to just have a class with function declarations in it, or I can put it in a named class or module, it does not matter.  There will only ever be one class in a file.

What I want to happen is read the contents of File A, get each method from the file.  I then want to overwrite these methods into the source of File B such that I get File C.

**File A (the file whose methods need inserted into File B)**

```
def show
  puts params[:rule_set_edition_id]
  @description = @rule.description
  @input_lines = @description.split("\\n")
  @output_lines = []
  for input_line in @input_lines do
    if input_line != "" then
      @output_lines << input_line
    end
  end

  @rule_set_edition 
end

def some_other_method
  puts "FooBar"
end
```

**File B (Part - Standard Rails Scaffold, before overwrite)**

```
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rule, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rules
  # GET /rules.json
  def index
    @rules = Rule.all
  end

  # GET /rules/1
  # GET /rules/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /rules/new
  def new
    @rule = Rule.new
  end

  # GET /rules/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  . . . etc

end
```

**File C (Part - The output file I want)**

```
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rule, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rules
  # GET /rules.json
  def index
    @rules = Rule.all
  end

  # GET /rules/1
  # GET /rules/1.json
  def show
    puts params[:rule_set_edition_id]
    @description = @rule.description
    @input_lines = @description.split("\\n")
    @output_lines = []
    for input_line in @input_lines do
      if input_line != "" then
        @output_lines << input_line
      end
    end

    @rule_set_edition 
  end

  def some_other_method
    puts "FooBar"
  end

  # GET /rules/new
  def new
    @rule = Rule.new
  end

  # GET /rules/1/edit
  def edit
  end
end
```

**Update**
NB: I realise this is wrong atm and am fixing it.

As I already have in my XMI Parser class a variable @models which has all the information on my XMI in a neat format I can add a function to my parser to hack the templates.

I used the code provided by @ChrisHeald, putting it in a file named hack_templates.rb and making it accept command line ARGV for the implementation and template file locations.

My new function then adds the lines for extra shell commands in my output.

```
    def hack_templates
      hacks = []
      for idref, model in @models do
        # Controllers
        controller_name = "#{model['name'].tableize}_controller.rb"
        controller_implementation = "./db/init/controllers/#{controller_name}"
        countroller_template = "./app/controllers/#{controller_name}"
        if File.exist?(countroller_template) and File.exist?(controller_implementation) then
          puts "ruby hack_template.rb #{controller_implementation} #{countroller_template}"
        end
        # Models

        # Views
      end
      hacks.join("\n")
    end
```

And the hack_templates.rb from the @ChrisHeald code:

```
require 'method_source'
include MethodSource::CodeHelpers

$implementation = open(ARGV[0])
$template = open(ARGV[1])

module Implementation
  class << self
    eval $implementation.read
  end
end

@template_by_line = $template.each_line.to_a

(Implementation.methods - Module.new.methods).each do |method|
  $implementation.rewind
  # Get the source code of our implementation method
  impl_source = expression_at $implementation, Implementation.method(method).source_location[1]

  # Get the line that this method starts on in the template
  template_line = @template_by_line.index {|line| line.match(/^\s*def #{method}/) }

  if template_line
    # If we found a match, replace it
    # Get the source code for the template method
    tmpl_source = expression_at @template_by_line, template_line + 1

    # Replace it with the implemetation method
    @template_by_line[template_line] = impl_source

    # Remove any extra lines from the template method
    tmpl_source.split(/\n/).length.times do |len|
      @template_by_line.delete_at template_line + len + 1
    end
  else
    # find the last `end` in the template array and insert the implementation source before it
    last_end = @template_by_line.rindex {|line| line.match(/^\s*end/)}
    @template_by_line.insert(last_end, "\n" + impl_source + "\n")
  end

end

File.open($template, "w+") do |f|
   f.syswrite(@template_by_line.join)
end
```

This will only work from the second run onwards as the controller would not exist at the point where I call this code unless an old one is there.  For me it is probably as easy just to run it twice but I could also send the hack_template.rb commands to a different file from the main output.sh

**Further Update**
In the end I ended up using Rails Concerns.  I create a new concern for each class, following a naming convention of ClassNameConcern.  I then put all of my class methods in a concern leaving my models with just auto-generated stuff.

Since I have like 100 models, of which 4 I have edited so far, this works well.  The answer by @ChrisHeald is still the correct answer for my question though.

Comment: Edit: ArgoXML should read ArgoUML

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example if what you're looking to do? This is probably doable, but I want to be sure I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Can you tweak the generator?

Comment: Brilliant idea. If you decide to create this, and open source it, I'll donate to your project. My advice is to look at [rubinius](http://rubini.us/) because it contains a ruby parser, and runtime.

Comment: If I clean it up then yeah I will stick it up somewhere.  It is quite rough around the edges at the moment though and I need a short write up on how it works (as I have restricted the UML Class Diagram to reflect how Rails works).  I have added an example inline.

Comment: @BradWerth, do you mean adjust the generator so that it automatically overwrites rather than replaces?  I could if there is a way to do that.  I am just trying to think if that will work for all cases.  My controller example is straightforward, it is some of the models which may get trickier.  If there is suitable merge functionality on the generator though

Comment: The state the XMI to Rails script is in at the moment is one where it creates a model or scaffold for each class.  Adds the attributes to generator (and therefore migration).  Looks through the relations and supports has_one, has_many and has_many :through, puts the generator commands in order (this was the bit that took a while) so that Rails does not throw a hissy fit when you reference something that has yet to be created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done. Working on a solution at the moment. But yeah, providing your own generator is probably a lot easier. :)

Comment: I updated the question showing what I have done with the template hacking code from @ChrisHeald, it works well with what I have in place.

Comment: @a2800276 whilst I appreciate edits on questions some of your suggested changes are either nit picking or miss the point.  For example I purposefully wrote "open classes" rather than "opening classes" because it is the given name for such a thing in the Ruby language (http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html).  I also wrote "to see if I could" rather than "to see if I can" because it was a past tense task which I did actually complete.  The rest of the edit it just some bold headers and the use of "First Off" rather than "Firstly" which is nothing but personal preference.

Comment: Tarod, I may have accidentally tried to revert your change.  It does not seem to have gone through, not sure if you need to approve it.  If so then reject it.  You were right, the tag source can be removed.   I was just trying to revert back the changes @a2800276 made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Generators

The easiest way to do this is going to be to just use a custom generator template.

> In Rails 3.0 and above, generators don't just look in the source root for templates, they also search for templates in other paths. And one of them is lib/templates. Since we want to customize Rails::Generators::HelperGenerator, we can do that by simply making a template copy inside lib/templates/rails/helper with the name helper.rb.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates

The template for a controller is here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/templates/controller.rb

So you could just create a copy of that in `lib/templates/rails/controller/controller.rb`, and customize it to be something like:

```
<% if namespaced? -%>
require_dependency "<%= namespaced_path %>/application_controller"
<% end -%>
<% module_namespacing do -%>
class <%= class_name %>Controller < ApplicationController

  def show
    puts params[:rule_set_edition_id]
    @description = @rule.description
    @input_lines = @description.split("\\n")
    @output_lines = []
    for input_line in @input_lines do
      if input_line != "" then
        @output_lines << input_line
      end
    end

    @rule_set_edition
  end

  def some_other_method
    puts "FooBar"
  end

<% (actions - [:show, :some_other_method]).each do |action| -%>
  def <%= action %>
  end
<%= "\n" unless action == actions.last -%>
<% end -%>
end
<% end -%>
```

Then, when you generate a controller, Rails will use your template (with your implementations).

That said, if these methods are common between all your generated controllers, you should consider simply inheriting your controllers from a common superclass, and then having the default implementation of `show` be something like:

```
def show
  super
end
```

There are also options for post-processing generated templates using `source_location` to detect method boundaries, but it's fiddly. I'm working on a proof-of-concept for that at the moment.

## Actually hacking up the templates

We're going to use the `method_source` gem, which uses `Method#source_location` to find where a method starts, and then evaluates lines until it finds a complete expression. Once we have that, then we can just replace the given method with our implementation.

This is fairly awful and I recommend against it if feasible.

#### implementation.rb

```
  def show
    puts params[:rule_set_edition_id]
    @description = @rule.description
    @input_lines = @description.split("\\n")
    @output_lines = []
    for input_line in @input_lines do
      if input_line != "" then
        @output_lines << input_line
      end
    end

    @rule_set_edition
  end

  def some_other_method
    puts "FooBar"
  end
```

#### template.rb

```
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rule, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rules
  # GET /rules.json
  def index
    @rules = Rule.all
  end

  # GET /rules/1
  # GET /rules/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /rules/new
  def new
    @rule = Rule.new
  end

  # GET /rules/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # . . . etc
end
```

#### converter.rb

```
require 'method_source'
include MethodSource::CodeHelpers

$implementation = open("implementation.rb")
$template = open("template.rb")

module Implementation
  class << self
    eval $implementation.read
  end
end

@template_by_line = $template.each_line.to_a

(Implementation.methods - Module.new.methods).each do |method|
  $implementation.rewind
  # Get the source code of our implementation method
  impl_source = expression_at $implementation, Implementation.method(method).source_location[1]

  # Get the line that this method starts on in the template
  template_line = @template_by_line.index {|line| line.match(/^\s*def #{method}/) }

  if template_line
    # If we found a match, replace it
    # Get the source code for the template method
    tmpl_source = expression_at @template_by_line, template_line + 1

    # Replace it with the implemetation method
    @template_by_line[template_line] = impl_source

    # Remove any extra lines from the template method
    tmpl_source.split(/\n/).length.times do |len|
      @template_by_line.delete_at template_line + len + 1
    end
  else
    # find the last `end` in the template array and insert the implementation source before it
    last_end = @template_by_line.rindex {|line| line.match(/^\s*end/)}
    @template_by_line.insert(last_end, "\n" + impl_source + "\n")
  end

end
puts @template_by_line.join
```

And some output:

```
$ ruby converter.rb
class RulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rule, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rules
  # GET /rules.json
  def index
    @rules = Rule.all
  end

  # GET /rules/1
  # GET /rules/1.json
  def show
    puts params[:rule_set_edition_id]
    @description = @rule.description
    @input_lines = @description.split("\\n")
    @output_lines = []
    for input_line in @input_lines do
      if input_line != "" then
        @output_lines << input_line
      end
    end

    @rule_set_edition
  end

  def new
    @rule = Rule.new
  end

  # GET /rules/1/edit
  def edit

  def some_other_method
    puts "FooBar"
  end  end

  # . . . etc
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will take a look at both methods and see what suits.  Actually hacking up the templates may be of benefit anyway instead of the Awk I am currently using.